# Hibernate and spring session configuration

Tags: spring, hibernate, session

i have a problem with Hiberante and Spring.

When i get an entity everything works, but if I use a subproperty the lazy load fails due to a close session... why hibernate close session so early? Can not wait to exit the service or take one session per thread?

This is my configuration

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.cinebot.db.entity</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

This is my dao:

```
@Transactional
public class Dao {


    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Session getSession(){
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T get(Class<T> classe, Serializable id) throws Exception {
        if(id==null) return null;
        T obj = (T) getSession().get(classe, id);
        return obj;
    }
```

}

and this is where i get the error (getEventi() is lazy loaded) inside a @Service class:

```
    Spettacoli spettacolo = dao.get(Spettacoli.class, spettacoloId);
   if(spettacolo.getEventi().getScadenza()>0) throw new LogicalException("Spettacolo scaduto");
```

Comment: Where you are accessing the entity properties?

Comment: in a @Service class just after getting that entity with  getSession().get()

Comment: Can you show service method code here including dao method? Need to have a look on transaction annotation

Comment: I edited the question with that infos... thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the entity outside the transaction.. You need to mark service method as transactional.

In your current code your transaction ends when your dao method completes so when you access that entity in your service method it is detached entity which will certainly thorw exception.

Remember you need to start transaction in service and not DAO which will allow you to access child entities. So move @transactional annotation to your service method.

Comment: Thank you Sunil, but i have a little more question. If i need a lazy property in my controller (for example) should I add Transactional also there?

Comment: No. You have to use transfer objects over there. See by design conventions you should never carry your entity to controller but use transfer objects to carry entity information. Transfer objects(TO) are simply java beans which will contains required fields from entity. This TO will be populated in service method